# Kernel Headers for Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 15.04

Today I upgraded by 14.10 VM to 15.04.  Since it's a virtual machine (via VirtualBox), I needed to install guest additions.  However, the installation fails saying (in `/var/log/vboxadd-install.log`):

> Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.16.0-31-generic cannot be found.

So, I tried to install it in the usual way and got:

> Package linux-headers-3.16.0-31-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.  This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source[.]

Having installed `linux-headers-generic`, which should provide the correct headers, I was confused.  This is the sort of error I would expect if `3.16.0-31` was out of date.  But . . . indeed `dpkg -l | grep generic` produces:

> ...
>   ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-17-generic ...
>   ...

A ha!  So it looks like the guest additions are trying to use an outdated kernel.  Maybe they use `uname`.  So I tried `uname -r` and got:

> 3.16.0-31-generic

---

My guess is that the guest additions are using `uname` to get the desired kernel header version, but that `uname` is giving the incorrect value for whatever reason.  **Question: If my analysis is right, how do I fix it?  If not, what's the problem?**

---

EDIT: After looking around, it seems that this means the running kernel is actually `3.16.0-31`, while `3.19.0-17` is merely *installed*.  I `sudo update-grub`d, confirmed that 3.19 kernel is the 0th element of `/boot/grub/menu.lst` and rebooted, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

EDIT: While `/boot/grub/menu.lst` is correct (the 0th entry is 3.19), on reboot and holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to get the manual menu, I do *not* see the 3.19 kernel, and the top entry is the 3.16 kernel.

Comment: `uname` probably (technically) isn't giving you the wrong value; That's saying that you're running kernel version 3.16 and not 3.19. Have you restarted the VM since the upgrade?

Comment: @saiarcot895 While I had rebooted, I just figured that and some other things out. See edit.

Comment: Do you have a display attached to the VM, from which you can see the boot, or are you SSH'ing in? If the latter, you could try getting rid of `linux-image-3.16.0-31-generic` and `linux-image-extra-3.16.0-31-generic`. That way, your VM will be forced to boot the latest kernel.

Comment: Also, make sure that the corresponding packages for 3.19.0-17 _are_ installed; you don't want to be left with an unbootable VM.

Comment: @saiarcot895 see 2nd edit. GrUB doesn't seem to be recognizing the 3.19 kernel on bootup at all, even though `update-grub` can _after_ booting into 3.16. I already tried purging/reinstalling grub to no avail.

Comment: @saiarcot895 I have forked it [into a separate question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/623922/why-cant-grub-find-a-kernel-that-it-already-found).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like upgrade process from 14.10 to 15.04 has a bug. Kernel does not install correctly. This can be fixed by running:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

This will pull both linux-image-generic and linux-headers-generic.

These meta packages always point to the latest kernel image and headers.

This is not the first question with this kind of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

fixed mine with:

```
uname -r
3.13.0-30-generic

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
reboot

uname -r
3.13.0-30-generic
```

??

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic
sudo reboot

uname -r
3.19.0-18-generic
```

followed by:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Comment: You need to make sure that headers are up to date too.